# docker build error when trying to pip install dict package

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu

I only started getting the error when I moved my docker installation onto ubuntu (things were working fine on windows docker installation).

When I run docker build I get the following error when it is trying to install *python* package `dict`:

```
#14 1.681   Downloading dict-2020.7.1.tar.gz (1.8 kB)
#14 2.134 ERROR: Requested dict from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/fb/6a2458c82f59b4aad53949776608d97a46483c403df1dc20c39b413efe10/dict-2020.7.1.tar.gz#sha256=b54864077239b94e33376650824185c5aa310d3bf5089da57769f68413b6a83f has different version in metadata: '0.0.0'
```

(*if I remove the dict package from the *requirements.txt* file the docker build works fine, but my application fails to run in docker as it can't find the dict package)

when I look at the version of the dict package on my machine  it shows version 0.0.0 even though the latest version is 2020.7.1?

Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

Comment: You should add the **requirements.txt** to the post.

Comment: You should try to add `--use-feature=2020-resolver` to the `pip` intallation command. According this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8707

Comment: thank you Karoly - that fixed the issue.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, I would appreciate if you would mark that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `--use-feature=2020-resolver` to the pip installation command. According this issue: github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8707